# How do I Display a Message across projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

We have one Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET solution with 22 projects, one of which is called ***BusinessLogic*** and one which is called ***Web***.

In ***BusinessLogic***, we have code to log errors, and it used by all projects in the solution.

```
public static Guid? StartDebugLog(String module, String method, String message)
{
    if (ApplicationSettings.IsDebugLogActive)
    {
        using (BPIContext context = SessionManager.CreateNewBPIContext)
        {
            DebugLog debugLogObject = new DebugLog();
            debugLogObject.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            debugLogObject.Module = module;
            debugLogObject.Method = method;
            debugLogObject.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (message == null)
                debugLogObject.Message = "(NULL)";
            else
                debugLogObject.Message = message;
            context.AddToDebugLog(debugLogObject);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return debugLogObject.ID;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that this routine is hiding important errors from our customers. Yes, they can go into the application logs, but simply starting the application creates over 100 entries in the application log. Finding errors would be a daunting task to ask of our customers.

I need a way for this routine to be able to display a basic message so that customers do not continue on, thinking everything is OK. Something like `alert("An error has occurred.")`, but the ***BusinessLogic** project does not have access to the ***Web*** project.

Is there a recommended way to create a CALLBACK or something? Most of my background is in Windows Forms where this would be simple. Something like this:

```
            ...
            context.AddToDebugLog(debugLogObject);
            context.SaveChanges();
            if (WebCallback != null)
            {
                WebCallback(debugLogObject);
            }
            return debugLogObject.ID;
            ...
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible in a Web environment. If it is not possible, that's an answer too.

For a *"Part 2"*, some of our newer modules are displayed by dropping them into an iFrame. Is there a way to create something that will allow information from the iFrame to pass to the parent? Currently, all messages that are sent in the iFrame appear to get lost.

Comment: Have you already taken a look at SignalR? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Are these projects running on different processes, or is this a monolith?

Comment: @insane_developer - it's all running as one big application. I take it that is *monolith*.

Comment: Can you add a log levels logic to your code? than you could use it to decide which log level or type will return a message to the client.

Comment: @ShayD, not without having to modify all of the calls to it. What I plan to do is modify the `String message` that is being sent in. If it begins with a header like `"WebDisplay: ...."`, then I will split the string to display the info as well as logging the message.

Comment: @jpCode, you can also consider adding an optional parameter that will get a default level on all of your calls. That will let you set the 'alert' level only where you like to return to the client

Comment: @ShayD - got it, but I still do not know how to get the information back to the **Web** Project and displayed by the Master page.

Comment: is `javascipt` is an option? have you tried `window.top`?

Comment: @ShayD - the project **BusinessLogic** does not have any web components. Adding web components to it would introduce web components to all of the other 20 projects in the solution. That's why I was looking for a way to do a simple callback or reference. I'm not sure if that can be done, though.

Comment: This is more of an application design flaw. If your method has some sort of error state, you can either return a value to indicate an error (usually in the event of common errors you can anticipate), or you can throw an exception. The calling code has to deal with the returned value and/or any exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: Well, if the main site all have a master page (perhaps web forms), then that event does run for each page render. You could set a session() value in that logger - and then in the site master page check the session value for erirr . and if yes, then simply display some control (maybe even a toast message) that states errors exist.  You could even say display an additional menu option on the menu bar, and have a toast message display for each page render. Clicking on the error menu item would then jump to a page to display errors or whatever. This of course depends on if you have a master page.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify what we have now without impacting every file that references the logging tool. I was hoping there would be a way to add a delegate that can be applied via the `Master.Page` file, but it sounds like nobody here knows how to do that.